# Use css to create a custom arrow shape

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I have a css arrow box overlaying an image slider but I need to make the tail indented and transparent so the image is seen behind it. Need the white portion to be transparent. See attached image and my css below. Thanks.[image: css arrow box over image]

```
#flag { 
width: 400px; height: 80px; background: #231f20; position: relative;
}

#flag:before { 
content: ""; 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 

width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 40px solid transparent; 

border-bottom: 40px solid transparent; 

border-left: 35px solid white;

}

#flag:after { 
content: ""; 
position: absolute; 
left: 400px; 
bottom: 0; 
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 40px solid transparent;

border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;

border-left: 45px solid #231f20;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change `border-left: 35px solid white;` to `solid transparent`?  Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: You can also use SVG masking : http://codepen.io/yoksel/full/fsdbu/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You just need to set the color of top/bottom borders of the `::before` pseudo-element to the background color and change the color of left border to transparent.

Then you could use margins/offsets to position the pseudo-element properly.

```css
body { background-color: gold; }

#flag { 
  width: 400px; height: 80px; background: #231f20; position: relative;
  margin-left: 35px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#flag:before { 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: -35px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 40px solid #231f20; 
  border-bottom: 40px solid #231f20; 
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;

}

#flag:after { 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 400px; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;

  border-left: 45px solid #231f20;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag">This is it!</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Simplest solution would be `svg`.

```css
html, body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="225" height="50">
  <path d="M0,0 L200,0 L225,25 L200,50 L0,50 L25,25z" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

---

You could easily create complex arrow shapes.

```css
html, body {
  background: teal;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="-5 -5 210 110">
  <path d="M0,0 L155,40 L145,0 L200,50 L145,100 L155,60 L0,100 Q100,50 0,0z" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#222222" stroke-width="5" fill="#333333" />
</svg>
```

---

Making it even more complex by adding some quadratic bezier curves.

```css
html,
body {
  background: teal;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="-5 -5 205 107">
  <path d="M0,0 L155,40 L145,0 L200,50 L145,100 L155,60 L0,100 Q45,87.5 10,75 Q55,65 20,50 Q55,37 10,25 Q45,12.5 0,0z" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#222222" stroke-width="5" fill="#333333" />
</svg>
```

---

Comment: simple as soon you come to *Compatibility*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Only IE8 isn't supported - http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: ok, but IE8  still has a tremendous market-share ~16%... and the mass of un-updated mobile and desktop browsers. +1 any way for pushing the web forward.

Comment: I would say this is a great solution. IE8 users wouldn't be able to see the SVG shape, but that would be a non-issue if one understands the concept of *progressive enhancement*.

Comment: @Terry agree, but there's no fallback use-case along with the AA

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am, and I am a proponent of progressive enhancement. This is not a personal discussion, please steer clear of personal attacks — especially one who has enough reps to show he has been around long enough to understand such ethics.

Comment: @Terry Agree with every single dot with you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:before`'s borders to draw the main rectangular part of the arrow, instead of a `background` on `#flag`. So set the `border-top` and `border-bottom` on `#flag:before` to be `#231f20`. That way, you can just set the `border-left` on `#flag:before` to be `transparent`.

Here's a modified version with different colors to help visualize which borders are drawing which part in this solution. http://jsfiddle.net/fuvwsn55/

Answer (score 1):

***[demo](http://jsbin.com/joqos/3/edit)***

```
#flag:before,
#flag:after{ 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  border: 40px solid #231f20;
}
#flag:before { 
  left: -35px;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
}
#flag:after {
  right:-80px;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid #231f20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can split your flag into two divs (definitely not practical in all cases) you can get a smoothly rendered arrow (note, this WILL also skew your divs' content):

```css
body
{
    background-color: gold;
}

#flag_top {
    width: 400px; height: 40px; background: #231f20; position: relative;
     -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
      -o-transform: skew(40deg);
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#flag_bottom {
    width: 400px; height: 40px; background: #231f20; position: relative;
     -webkit-transform: skew(320deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(320deg);
      -o-transform: skew(320deg);
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag_top">
</div>
<div id="flag_bottom">    
</div>
```